# Avoid no-unused-expession warning in ESLint using "&&"-operator

Tags: typescript, eslint

If I do the following in TypeScript, ESLint complains about the "no-unused-expession" rule:

```
!hasSelectedValues && this.loadOptions([]);
```

How can I make ESLint understand that this expression (hasSelectedValues) is not "unused" ? I do **not** want to remove the rule for unused expressions completely.

Comment: That's not an error from TypeScript, it's from [ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-expressions).

Comment: That's excatly what that rule is about. You are not using the result of this expression. IMHO it's bad style to "abuse" an `&&` as `if`. ESLint interprets it, that you are calculating something, but forgot to assign the result,,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid running into that [ESLint error](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-expressions), don't use `&&` for side effects, use an `if`:

```
if (!hasSelectedValues) {
    this.loadOptions([]);
}
```

or if you really want to keep it terse:

```
if (!hasSelectedValues) this.loadOptions([]);
```

> How can I make ESLint understand that this expression (hasSelectedValues) is not "unused" ?

It's not complaining about `hasSelectedValues`, it's complaining about the result of the `&&` operator, which your code isn't using. `!hasSelectedValues && this.loadOptions([]);` is an expression that has a result (`false` or the return value of `this.loadOptions([])`). That's the unusued value from the expression.

Comment: Ok. But why would you not use &&?

Comment: Because this isn't Code Golf. Make your intentions clear. What does `loadOptions` do, more specifically, what does it _return_ and why do you think it's a good idea to ignore that but use `&&` to conditionally execute it anyway?

Comment: @PhilippSengelmann because when you want to use a conditional statement, you use an `if`. When you want to do a logical expression that returns a value, you use a `&&`. If you type in `2 + 2;` as a statement by itself, it is useless and suggests an error on the programmer's side. If you really want to say "no, I actually meant to write that", you should be writing the idiomatically correct thing.